# Morris.js area chart - wrong scale on the Y-axis (possible bug?)

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I'm looking at the example of morris.js area chart on this page: http://jqueryajaxphp.com/preview/charts/ and I've noticed that the author is using a json data feed there, which starts as:

```
"area" : {
    "area1" : {
         "y": "2006",
         "a": "31",
         "b": "84"
    },
    "area2" : {
         "y": "2007",
         "a": "12",
         "b": "25"
    },
```

but on the graph we have:

[image]

as you can see the Series B has a value of 84, but on the graph it's way above the value of 100. Is it a bug or am I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the series are stacking. This is the default behavior. In [the documentation](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html) you find that using `behaveLikeLine` set to `true` you can disable this stacking, so that the areas are overlayed.

For example ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6d40L0bo/)):

```
Morris.Area({
  element: 'area-example',
  behaveLikeLine: true,
  data: [
    { x: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
    { x: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { x: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { x: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { x: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { x: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { x: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
  ],
  xkey: 'x',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']
});
```

Note that this functionality does not seem to work with Morris 0.4.1, but does work in 0.5.1.